# Import model without id field as primary key with django import_export

Tags: django, django-import-export

just tried out django-import-export to import som things from a csv-file.
Followed the doc but I always get an error when trying to import the following Model:

```
class Token(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(db_index=True,unique=True,primary_key=True,    )
    pool = models.ForeignKey(Pool, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    state = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=State.VALID, choices=State.choices)
```

then the resource class:

```
class TokenResource(resources.ModelResource):
class Meta:
    model = Token
    skip_unchanged = True
    report_skipped = True
    fields = "key"
```

Now when importing a csv-file i get the following errors:

```
Error

row number: 1 - 'id'

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/backend/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 667, in import_row
instance, new = self.get_or_init_instance(instance_loader, row)
File "/backend/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 359, in get_or_init_instance
instance = self.get_instance(instance_loader, row)
File "/backend/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 346, in get_instance
import_id_fields = [
File "/backend/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 347, in <listcomp>
self.fields[f] for f in self.get_import_id_fields()
KeyError: 'id'
```

There is no field id within my model the primary key field is key so why it is not taken?

Or could it be that a model must have an id field to get imported? I know that this ids are taken for comparision and so on but there is a primary key field within the model, so I do not understand why this is not taken.

How could I change this without having to rename my model? I could not find a hint within the docs.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry it is in the docs: https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html?highlight=import_id_fields#customize-resource-options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There is no field id within my model the primary key field is key so why it is not taken?

The default field for identifying whether an object exists or not is called 'id'.  However you can override using [`import_id_fields`](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#key-error-id-in-get-import-id-fields), so in your case the following should work:

```py
class TokenResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Token
        skip_unchanged = True
        report_skipped = True
        import_id_fields = ("key",)

        # you can optionally use 'fields' as a whitelist for 
        # fields to be imported
        fields = ("key",)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I have a weir problem if I want to import toke keys. If the model is created and saved the key field is empty, I could see that this is because of 

import_export.resources.ModelResource.init_instance where return self._meta.model() returna an Instance without a key. Am I missing something here?

Comment: check that the csv field name matches the attribute name (you can use the attribute keyword when declaring the field if not). Check that 'key' is in your fields list.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to set up the class Meta of your resource with `import_id_fields=("your_model_primary_key")`:

```
from import_export import resources
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

class TokenResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Token
        import_id_fields = ("your_model_primary_key",)
```

For django-import-export versions over 2.9.0 `resource_class` has been deprecated in favour of `resource_classes` which should be declared as a list or tuple

```
class TokenAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_classes = [TokenResource]
    # rest of the code
```